# Using calc with stacked raster bricks

Tags: r, raster, lm

I'm trying to run a linear model across two raster bricks in R. The two bricks are from different sources, but as far as I can tell have the same dimensions (lon, lat, time). I am getting the error: *"Error in dimnames(x) <- dn : length of 'dimnames' [2] not equal to array extent".*

My code:

```
#stack two raster bricks
s <- stack(rasterbrick1, rasterbrick2)

fun=function(x) { if (is.na(x[1])){ NA } else { lm(x[1:15] ~ x[16:30])$coefficients[2] }}
slope <- calc(s, fun)
```

dimnames() for both rasters are NULL. Both rasters have the same dimensions (360 720 15). Both rasters have the same names(). The function works fine when I use raster2 and raster3, which are from the same source. Clearly there is some sort of mismatch between rasterbrick1 and rasterbrick2, but I have no idea how to figure out what it is, since everything I've checked matches.

I know this may be difficult to answer since it seems to be data-specific, but any help is greatly appreciated, even if you can just give me some ideas of what elements to look at to pinpoint the mismatch.

Edit: I'm not sure how to show s (please tell me if there's a better way), but here is head(s) - the beginning of the data set is primarily zeros and NA.

```
index_2002.1 index_2003.1 index_2004.1 index_2005.1 index_2006.1 index_2007.1 index_2008.1
[1,]            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
[2,]            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
[3,]            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
 index_2009.1 index_2010.1 index_2011.1 index_2012.1 index_2013.1 index_2014.1 index_2015.1
[1,]            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
[2,]            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
[3,]            0            0            0            0            0            0            0
 index_2016.1 index_2002.2 index_2003.2 index_2004.2 index_2005.2 index_2006.2 index_2007.2
[1,]            0          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
[2,]            0          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
[3,]            0          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
index_2008.2 index_2009.2 index_2010.2 index_2011.2 index_2012.2 index_2013.2 index_2014.2
[1,]          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
[2,]          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
[3,]          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN          NaN
index_2015.2 index_2016.2
[1,]          NaN          NaN
[2,]          NaN          NaN
[3,]          NaN          NaN
```

traceback() gives the following:

```
traceback()
13: `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "layer")
12: .local(x, ...)
11: getValues(x)
10: getValues(x)
9: apply(getValues(x), 2, FUN = function(x) {
   c(min(x, na.rm = TRUE), max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
})
8: setMinMax(x)
7: setMinMax(x)
6: .local(x, values, ...)
5: setValues(out, x)
4: setValues(out, x)
3: .local(x, fun, ...)
2: calc(s, fun)
1: calc(s, fun)
```

Comment: Can you show `s` and the output of `traceback()` after the error occurs?

Comment: Just added them. Not sure how to best show s, since it's a large raster stack, but I added head(s). Please let me know if there's a better way.